# using a variable from a drop-down within a sql query

Tags: php, sql

I have a drop down menu and I would like to use the selection in a query.

Say I have the following, this is actually loaded from a db on my site but to limit the amount of code I post:

```
<select id="parent" name="parent">
<option value="P1">parent 1</option>
<option value="P2">parent 2</option>
</select>
```

I want to query the child table for P1 or P2 depending on what was selected so I have the following query:

```
$selected_parent=$_REQUEST['parent'];<-- Not sure if this is right at all

$query = "SELECT parent.*, child.* 
          FROM parent 
          INNER JOIN child 
          ON parent.value = child.parent
          WHEN parent.value = '$selected_parent'";
```

I would have the two following tables:

```
PARENT                 CHILD
ID   NAME     VALUE    ID    NAME    PARENT
01---parent1--P1       01----child1--P1
02---parent2--P2       02----child2--P1
03---parent3--P2       03----child3--P2
```

I know this is open to SQL Injection, I will fix it later, more curious as to how the variable working within a query

EDIT: Currently I get no results when using '$selected_parent.'

Thanks in advance

Comment: so when you tested it the issue was what ?

Comment: currently I don't get any results

Comment: Try echoing the query and running it manually against the DB. I wonder if `WHEN` in the query should be `WHERE`? `WHEN` is not an SQL keyword  I am familiar with, although it may be propriety to some DB engine or other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're extremely close, the only change I can see would be to wrap the dropdown box in a form tag, such as:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['php_self']; ?>" method="POST">
    <select id="parent" name="parent">
        <option value="P1">parent 1</option>
        <option value="P2">parent 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And then when you're getting the variable, use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST:

```
$selected_parent=$_POST['parent'];
```

Other than that your query should work just fine.

Comment: Its already in form tags, though my action is set to another processing page. But you got me thinking, am i able to have this dynamically grab the child, or does it need to process through a reload?

Answer (score 0):

`WHEN` is not valid syntax in your query. Use `WHERE`.

Comment: fixed the typo, didn't fix my problem though

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be setting parent.value to the string constant '$selected_parent' rather than to the value of $selected_parent.

I don't know php, but I would have thought that you would need to write

```
WHEN parent.value = '" + $selected_parent + "'";
```

(Sorry if I've got the concatenation operator wrong. I only use C#.)